# Changing a cell value in a duplicate row

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates

Thanks in advance for any help, i'm having a mental block!

It's a long story as to why but I have a table like the following:

```
Start Date  End Date    Reference
02/07/2017  01/07/2018  2331851720712
01/04/2017  31/12/2017  1200025264898
01/02/2017  31/12/2017  1200025264912
08/05/2017  07/06/2017  2000054765267
10/06/2017  10/07/2017  2000054765267
```

The bottom two rows have the same reference number AND the End Date of the first occurance is in the same month as the Start Date of the second occurance. When this happens I need the first occurance End date to change to the 31st of the previous month.

Any thoughts would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: What did you try? Please show the code of your attempt, we need to know where your difficulties are and where you got stuck. Otherwise it looks like a *please do all the work for me* question, which I hope it is not.

Comment: Firstly I tried adding an additional column, then having a countif to count if that reference number appeared again, then creating additional columns and using the offset function to do checks and changes. However the reference numbers are not always in order.

Comment: ① reference numbers *not* in order makes it much harder. Is it allowed to sort them? What order are the data rows now? Maybe you can sort them back after running the macro? ② You tagged your question VBA so please show the VBA code you have tried. Formulas might not help here I think.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Sub test()

    Dim first_occ, second_occ As String
    Dim lrow As Integer
    Dim pre_month, first_occ_month, second_occ_month As String


    lrow = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

    For x = 2 To lrow

        first_occ = Cells(x, 3).Value
        second_occ = Cells((x + 1), 3).Value

        If (first_occ = second_occ) Then

        first_occ_date = Format(Cells(x, 2).Value, "d/m/yyyy")
        first_occ_month = Month(Format(Cells(x, 2).Value, "d/m/yyyy"))
        second_occ_month = Month(Format(Cells((x + 1), 1).Value, "d/m/yyyy"))

            If first_occ_month = second_occ_month Then
            Lastday = DateSerial(Year(first_occ_date), Month(first_occ_date), 0)
            Cells(x, 2).Value = Lastday
            Cells(x, 2).NumberFormat = "d/m/yyyy"
            End If

        End If

    Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: ① Note that if you `Dim pre_month, first_occ_month, second_occ_month As String` only the last variable is of type `String` but all the others are automatically of type `Variant` if no type is specified. You need to specify a type for **every** variable in VBA: `Dim pre_month As String, first_occ_month As String, second_occ_month As String` ② `pre_month` is never used, remove declaration. ③ Variables for row counting `lrow` must be of type `Long` Excel has more rows than `Integer` can handle.

Answer (score 1):

Sorted, then date adjusted.

```
Sub fixEndDate()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, arr As Variant

    With Worksheets("sheet2")
        With .Range(.Cells(1, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp))
            .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns(3), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                        Key2:=.Columns(1), Order2:=xlAscending, _
                        Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes
        End With

        For i = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
            If .Cells(i, "C").Value2 = .Cells(i + 1, "C").Value2 And _
               Format(.Cells(i, "B").Value2, "mmyy") = _
               Format(.Cells(i + 1, "A").Value2, "mmyy") Then
                .Cells(i, "B") = DateSerial(Year(.Cells(i, "B").Value2), Month(.Cells(i, "B").Value2), 0)
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Make an auxiliar column with the Real End Date you need. You can use this formula:

`=IF(MONTH(B2)=MONTH(A3);EOMONTH(B2;-1);B2)`

[image]

Comment: Worth to say, that this is only working if data is sorted by `SortField1 = Reference` AND `SortField2 = Start Date` because the OP said *"However the reference numbers are not always in order"*.